# Calculate $\int_0^1f(x)dx$ if

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

If $$f(x)=x+\int_0^1{(x+t)tf(t)}dt$$

find

$$\int_0^1f(x)dx$$

Any Hints would be helpful. I have no leads so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Let 
$$f(x)=mx+c$$
Find $m$ and $c$ first.

Comment: How did we decide its a linear function?

Comment: It's given that it's linear. Isn't it? The definite integrals are just constants.

Comment: Oh, got it. Thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 5):

Let $\displaystyle A=\int_0^1tf(t)dt$ and $\displaystyle B=\int_0^1t^2f(t)dt$.

Then $f(x)=(A+1)x+B$.

$$A=\int_0^1 tf(t)dt=\int_0^1[(A+1)t^2+Bt]dt=\frac{1}{3}(A+1)+\frac{1}{2}B$$

$$B=\int_0^1 t^2f(t)dt=\int_0^1[(A+1)t^3+Bt^2]dt=\frac{1}{4}(A+1)+\frac{1}{3}B$$

Solve for $A$ and $B$.